# How write UnitTest for Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, unit-of-work

I am exploring CodeCamper project by JohnPapa on github
https://github.com/johnpapa/CodeCamper. This is a ASP.Net SPA application and I am also working on similar project.

I interested to write some UnitTests for WebAPI controller. Controller contractor requires UnitofWork instanse and UnitofWork is initiate in Application_Start method.

When I run my UnitTest project UnitofWork object is null. How I can initiate UnitofWork from UnitTest project so that I can run my test methods. I hope make myself clear.

Here is a sample UnitTest method for following controller.

[LookupsController.cs](https://github.com/johnpapa/CodeCamper/blob/master/CodeCamper.Web/Controllers/LookupsController.cs)

UserControllerTest.cs

```
    [TestClass]
    public class UserControllerTest : ApiBaseController
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetRoomsTest()
        {
            var controller = new LookupsController(Uow);
            var result = controller. GetRooms().Any();
            Assert.IsTrue(result);
        }
    }
```

Again why **Uow** is null? What should I do, so that I can write unit test methods for this type of project/architecture.

For more detail about code you can check github repo.https://github.com/johnpapa/CodeCamper

Comment: You can probably use a Mock framework like Moq to create a new mock instance for the UoW interface, and pass that mock instance to the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any mocking framework to create a fake/stub/mock for `ICodeCamperUow` (below I am using [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/)):

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetRoomsTest()
{
  // UOW we need to use
  var fakeUOW = Substitute.For<ICodeCamperUow>();

  // setting up room repository so that it returns a collection of one room
  var fakeRooms = Substitute.For<IRepository<Room>>();
  var fakeRoomsQueryable = new[]{new Room()}.AsQueryable();
  fakeRooms.GetAll<Room>().Returns(fakeRoomsQueryable);

  // connect UOW with room repository
  fakeUOW.Rooms.Returns(fakeRooms);

  var controller = new LookupsController(fakeUOW);
  var result = controller.GetRooms().Any();
  Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

Please consider reading [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/) which is a great book to learn about unit testing.

Comment: Now I have instance of UnitOfWork that's good but still Uow.Rooms always returns zero(0). But when I use same method via application it return me all room. Why?

Comment: @MohsinJK The thing with fake objects: You can set them up any way you want but you need to set them up. Only you know how.

Comment: Not exactly i am still not able to add a object in fake Uow.

Comment: What and where exactly do you want to add?

Comment: In my project I also have Post method for adding new object. I am using that object for insert one object in memory but I can't add the fake Uow of is still empty. I don't know how can I add object in memory for unit testing.

Comment: @meike Can send you my application? So that you can easy notify my problem

Comment: Sure. Can you see my e-mail on my account?

Comment: What is your plan? Who sends who what?